# Extract the longest edge of a mesh generated by pdetool

Tags: matlab, mesh, pde

When I generate a mesh with pdetoolbox, like the one in the image. How can I extract the norm (longest edge value) of the mesh? I tried reading the documentation of "pdetool" and found the "MaxElementSize" property in the "FEMesh Properties". Although I don't know how to use "MaxElementSize" in the PDE Toolbox GUI.

[image]

Comment: Hi Gonzalo, welcome to SO.  Can you provide a bit more detail regarding what you have tried so far, and why it hasn't worked. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @TimOgilvy Ok, I tried adding more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the toolbox menu, select `Mesh` then `Export Mesh`:

[image]

You will then have the option to change variable name. The important ones here are the first two, i.e. names for *points* and *edges*. In this example, I keep them as defaults, i.e. `p` for *points* and `e` for *edges*.

`points` is a 2*n matrix, each column is represents the X- and Y-coordinates of a vertex. `e` is a 7*n matrix, each column being the parameters for constructing an edge. The first two rows is the index of the vertices of the edge and the rests are not of interest here.

```
% Each edge is bounded by two vertices. 
% Extract the coordinates of the first set of vertices.
e1 = p(:,e(1,:)); 
% Extract the coordinates of the second set of vertices.
e2 = p(:,e(2,:));
% Calculate the square distance.
dsqr = sum((e1 - e2).^2);
% Take the maximum.
[dsqrMax, idx] = max(dsqr);
% Length of the longest edge
dMax = sqrt(dsqrMax);
```

`idx` is the index of the longest edge in `e` matrix. You can extract all information of the edge by `e(:,idx);`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, this is just what I was looking for :)